# Entity Framework slower than LinqToSql

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have 70.000 records in table. When i am trying to get all records with entityframework it nearly takes about 20 seconds. On the other hand when try to get all records with linqtosql it takes about 2 seconds. Why entityframework works too slower than linqtosql. Do i need to make any customization for entityframework to works faster.

Comment: Maybe you are loading some related entities, the gap is too big. Can you profile the queries?

Answer (score 1):

A more fair test would be to return an anonymous type in both queries and than compare the speeds. This way the resulting object from both `linq-to-sql` and `entity-framework` will be the same

For example:

```
var query = from x in context.Entity
            select new
            {
              x.Property1,
              x.Property2,
              .
              .
              .
            };
```